# Upgrade TeamCity

Tags: postgresql, teamcity

I have problem with upgrade TeamCity version 2017.1.1 to 2017.1.2.
This problem concerns the work of TeamCity and PostgreSQL.
What I do:

1. Stop teamcity proccess `/etc/init.d/teamcity stop`;
2. Delete home directory TeamCity `rm /opt/JetBrains/TeamCity`;
3. Download newer version TeamCity (2017.1.2) and untar in home directory TeamCity;
4. Start teamcity proccess `/etc/init.d/teamcity start`.

After this I have problem TeamCity and PostgreSQL:

1. [before delete schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZ8BM.png);
2. [after delete schema and create new schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDEH3.png).

The only way is to reinstall DB. But this is a very questionable procedure, but this working.

Answer (score 0):

Seems, that TeamCity was unable to find the previous database settings file. And so, it decides that it's a new server installation.

Maybe a data directory for TeamCity isn't in the default location (that is {HOME_DIRECTORY}/.BuildServer).

If it's the case - you need to put teamcity-startup.properties in the TeamCity/conf directory (with content "teamcity.data.path=/path_to_TeamCity_data_directory").

Answer (score 0):

This problem with incorrect stop service. Need use this step:

1. sudo service teamcity stop
2. /etc/init.d/teamcity stop
3. Update TeamCity
4. sudo service teamcity start
5. /etc/init.d/teamcity start
6. sudo systemctl daemon-reload